# ejabberdctl not found in bash Ubuntu(installing ejabberd)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, erlang, ejabberd

I was trying to install ejabberd with applying the tutorials in many site to my VM which is ubuntu but I am stuck in the beginning. After I wrote

```
sudo  apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install ejabberd
```

it installs ejabberd. But when I try to write the following

```
 ejabberdctl register admin localhost mypassword
```

it says ejabberdctl not found. I also tried to restart it with but it is still same.

```
sudo service ejabberd restart
```

Note: I did not install erlang seperately. Can it be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo ejabberdctl`,

if it didn't work, Do:

```
sudo updatedb
sudo locate ejabberdctl
```

check if the output is in your $PATH variable.